# Solve my picture riddle! Cowards need not apply!

Tags: riddle, visual

Something connects these images:

[image: Little finger]

[image: Gold nuggets]

[image: Rubber band ball]

[image: Dog Scratching]

[image: Electrical wire]

[image: Drumsticks]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Comment: So it's a visual riddle of pictures - but it's *not* a rebus?

Comment: I was going to post an answer tying it all to games of thrones but had trouble coming up with a connection for rubber band ball and drumsticks.

Comment: @n_palum It looked like rebus might fit based on the tag description but it doesn't seem to fit definitions of a rebus found elsewhere.  I wouldn't know myself.

Comment: I had just been asking for clarification mostly, I wasn't necessarily saying it was a rebus - and since then I have been told these are in fact not rebus puzzles and visual/riddle fit these fine.

Comment: @n_palum Fair enough.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They may all be connected by

> chicken

for images representing

> [Chicken *Little*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_Little_(2005_film))
>
>  Chicken *nuggets*
>
>   [*Rubber* chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_chicken)
>
>   [Chicken *scratch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_scratch_(disambiguation))
>
>   Chicken *wire*
>
>  Chicken *drumsticks*

And the title 'Cowards need not apply!'

> Chicken can mean scared

Comment: I would have never guessed it, as I am a vegetarian guy. Biased question

Comment: @L.K. That's not a valid excuse. You only know about things you eat? Pffff. Would you have used the same excuse if the answer was "a brick", or "football stadium"? https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-10/16/11/enhanced/webdr09/enhanced-22995-1445009510-7.png

Comment: 5 new phrases… :/

Comment: for your third one, switch the word order to create a more idiomatic phrase.

Comment: I agree with Kate on the 3rd one.  Either that or just go with "Chicken Ball" to fit your format.

Comment: Also relevant: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7HX-Ktk6_7g/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: wait.... WHAT? @L.K. I honestly hope you aren't being serious :/.... by THAT logic, any and all questions are biased against someone at some point in time...

Comment: Sorry about the late reply.  You got it! +1

Comment: @KateGregory +1 That's what I was thinking of

Comment: @Marius +1 because brilliantly logical rants that put down daft people and whiney herbivores at the same time deserve +1s

Comment: Thanks @KateGregory - I switched the 3rd - my order looked like a timid masseur.

Answer (score 5):

I have an alternate interpretation for part of it

> Hand: Chicken Fingers
>
>  Wires: Chicken Strips (It's stripped wire)

But then again

> maybe I'm just hungry

Answer (score 2):

> little finger,
>  gold nugget,
>  rubber band,
>  dog,
>  wire,
>  Chinese chopsticks
>  … chinese olympic team?
>  They are little, lots of gold, elastic (gymnastics), china is known for eating dogs, working together as team (you need all wires to turn on something) and mainly chinese

Comment: The last picture is of drumsticks, though.

Comment: hand, gold, elastic, flea, copper, drumsticks… nope, no idea... maybe ASL, but that fits only for 3... , unless you say gold in asl as it is in picture one

Comment: @JanIvan The first in ASL would be the letter i

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer

What I got was

> "A promise (pinky finger) is a precious (gold nuggets) and powerful (electric cord) thing (chopsticks)"

..Dog scratching and Rubber Ball din't fit my aforementioned quote.. so  -_-

Comment: If your answer doesn't fit, maybe put `#Partial Answer` at the top of the post so people know that it's only partial and can improve it for you? Also, can you put the important parts of your answer in spoilers (`>! ` at the start of each line)? Thanks!

Comment: @boboquack, thanks. I'll play according to the rules here.