# Another big picture question

Tags: riddle, visual

A single word connects these images:

[image: Watering Can]

[image: Cotton Balls]

[image: The Incredible Hulk]

[image: A Smart Car]

[image: A Glass Full of Water]

[image: A Motor]

[image: Dirty Hands]

What's the word, and what are the connections?

Comment: is it H2O.......?

Comment: @AmruthA It is not...

Comment: What is that second picture... wadding? As in to stop nose bleedings?

Comment: @MikeLimburg Cotton balls

Comment: Ahh.. I see. Then my answer doesn't quiet fit that picture :(

Comment: Is that a mini or a smart car?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's a smart car.  I don't know who makes it... (Update: appears to be a Merc)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's a actually a Smart ForTwo, not even a Mini...

Comment: To all that keep asking "Is that a bird, is that a plane?"...All I want to say is that Brent is a nice guy and already said which is which. If you click on the [edit](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/50913/edit) button you will see what every picture represents.

Comment: Are we looking for one word to combine these things with like in [this riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50892/solve-my-picture-riddle-cowards-need-not-apply) or for one word that has a connection to these things like in [this answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50913/another-big-picture-question/50916#50916)?

Comment: You're looking for a word that relates to something in each picture, like the accepted answer to my previous riddle  @theRavenQueen  +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It could be

> Mouth

As in

> Mouth-**watering**
>  [**Cotton**mouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agkistrodon_piscivorus)
>  [**Smash** Mouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smash_Mouth)
>  **Smart** mouth
>  Mouth**ful**
>  **Motor** mouth
>  **Dirty** mouth
>
>  And the title: **Big** mouth *(Thanks [@Tom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50913/another-big-picture-question/50924#comment156002_50924) for pointing this out)*

Comment: Nice answer to a nice puzzle! The *big* in the title also fits.

Comment: Aaah I had cotton mouth but was looking for snake connections! Well done!

Answer (score 5):

I think the connecting word might be

> Mouth

1)

> Mouth Watering:  Delicious

2)

> Cotton Mouth:  a type of snake, or a side-effect

3)

> Smash Mouth:  (via Hulk SMASH), a popular Band

4)

> Smart Mouth:  A sassy person

5)

> Mouth Glass:  A dentist's tool

6)

> Motor Mouth:  Someone who talks quickly and incessantly

7)

> Filthy/Dirty Mouth:  Someone who curses

Comment: Bah, should've made a placeholder answer while I typed it up!

Comment: I know.  Well explained too!  :P

Answer (score 4):

Are you probably talking about...

> Minecraft?

Because:

> A watering can is an [item](https://ftbwiki.org/Watering_Can) you can make.
>  ***Wrong answer!*** Wadding (wedding): It has been a [news article](http://thegoodness.com/matt-and-asias-minecraft-wedding/) two Minecraft players got married
>  Hulk is a [skin](http://www.minecraftskins.com/search/skin/she-hulk/1/) for your character
>  Minecraft is known for a lot of cool buildings, e.g. [smart cars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzkUh3Yxfog)
>  [Water](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Water) is a tile block
>  [Generator](https://minecraftcommand.science/tool-generator) to generate weapons with
>  [Dirt](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Dirt) is a tile block

Comment: Nope...  Not at all.  But wow... some strong connections I'd never have expected. +1

Comment: Ok.  Since the smart car update, I'm starting to wonder how many riddles/rebuses "Minecraft" couldn't be the answer to lol.  A quick google search definitely makes it look like you can grow cotton in minecraft too. https://www.google.nl/search?q=cotton+minecraft&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-Address&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicsIHc1p7TAhXjFZoKHROeBjoQ_AUICCgB&biw=2133&bih=1104&dpr=0.9#imgrc=VnaQL5aIJyt2-M:&spf=190  Minecraft is making my puzzle broad!

Comment: I just thought of Minecraft because of the Water and Dirt ... started to think about what Minecraft is used for (creating cars, big buildings... yesterday I saw a team made Hogwarts?) and all pieces fit perfectly. But you're right about Minecraft being huge. I am just not sure how many people know Minecraft on PSE ;)

Comment: I'm not knocking the idea.  It's actually a good fit!  Maybe it's just a coincidence in this puzzle or maybe minecraft has become a very modern puzzle-master-key like Death or Time or God!  :P

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Baseball

First clue

> 

Second clue

> Cotton Ball - Base'ball' player Jharel 'Cotton'

Third Clue

> Hulk smash - Baseball smash

Fourth Clue

> Smart car - Smart baseball

Fifth Clue

> 

Sixth Clue

> Electric Motor - Motor City Baseball Club

Seventh Clue

> Dirt - Baseball dirt

Comment: It's not.  I'm from the UK...  I still think of baseball as rounders played by men.  Other than that, I know nothing about it.  I'll bet those are probably decent fits though... +1

Answer (score 2):

I only have a few, but it might be this:

> Candy

How they fit the ones I have:

> Cotton candy  (Cotton balls)
> Smarties (Smart car)

Turns out wrong though. Another answer which fits a couple is

> Snake - cottonmouth and mudsnake, but the rest don't fit.

Comment: Nice.  (+1) But no. lol

Comment: @BrentHackers damn. Thats the only thing I can relate cotton to :P

Comment: I'm ssorry I made this a bit more tricky than usual.

Comment: @BrentHackers The only other 'cotton' relation I can think of is the cottonmouth snake, but snake doesn't fit anything else, except 'mudsnake'

Comment: Are you fishing for hints?  For shame.  You've solved far trickier than this.  I tested it on my slowest office buddy and he got it eventually. :)

Comment: @BrentHackers not fishing for hints, basically just saying I'm stuck :P

Comment: Well being stuck not 1,000,000 miles away from the right track isn't so bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56993/discussion-between-brent-hackers-and-beastly-gerbil).

Answer (score 2):

[2nd not likely guess]

Are you

> Joe?

Because:

> Joe Morzuch created the painting about a [watering can](http://www.joemorzuch.com/#/works/archive?i=322)
>  Cotton, Cotton Eye Joe
>  Joe Fixit is [an alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics)) for The Hulk
>  Joe is a **smart** [shop](http://joevsmartshop.com/)
>  [Water Joe](http://waterjoe.com/)
>  Slobberbone - [Engine Joe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnPSV6DqBIw)
>  And last but not least, you are a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245686/)

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing

> Clean

Because

> It just seams like every picture represents something clean or natural except the hands that needs to be cleaned. The hulk I assume could be radiation from nuclear stuff that is considered clean energy. And the motor I assume is an electrical motor.

Comment: This could be a good answer if you can answer how the things relate to cleaning.

Comment: I dont mean cleaning. I mean like watering is clean nutrition(?), Sugar Im not too sure about but it's natural, Hulk = nuclear = clean energy, smart cars run on clean energy, water is just considered clean in general, electrical motor is clean energy, hands should be cleaned